# Guests are masters?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, malach-angel, vayera, hachnasat-orchim-guests

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.19.2.1?with=Commentary) to Genesis 19:2 said that Lot called the angels his masters because:

> "וַיֹּאמֶר הִנֶּה נָּא־אֲדֹנַי סוּרוּ נָא אֶל־בֵּית עַבְדְּכֶם וְלִינוּ וְרַחֲצוּ רַגְלֵיכֶם וְהִשְׁכַּמְתֶּם וַהֲלַכְתֶּם לְדַרְכְּכֶם וַיֹּאמְרוּ לֹּא כִּי בָרְחוֹב נָלִין׃"
>
> "**הנה נא אדני.** הִנֵּה נָא אַתֶּם אֲדוֹנִים לִי אַחַר שֶׁעֲבַרְתֶּם עָלַי."
>
> Behold now you are my lords since you have passed by me.

What does he mean?
How does someone become a lord by passing another?
Please elaborate.

Comment: That's how seriously even Lot, who was no Abraham, took hospitality.  A simple passer-by was his "master".

Comment: @JoshK how can i understand that?, what does that mean, is it just a figure of speech?

Comment: Yes, @hazoriz, in the end it's just another way of saying "I am your faithful servant" i.e. you are an honored guest.

Comment: Please note that Lot uses אדני as an unholy name (with Patach, not Komotz), referring to them as real humans flesh and bones, but Abraham said Adonoy (with Komotz) stressing that he was addressing the Shechinah. That makes things much simpler (as JoshK mentioned) - once the people passed by he felt obligated to serve them.

Comment: @AlBerko why is that not similar to avoda zarah?

Comment: @hazoriz  What's "that"? Serving people is not considered idolatry AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

Rashi is saying that the usage of the expression 'Na' (נא) has a connotation of something that is occurring in the present. And so the meaning is, '*You are Lords presently, since you have passed by me.'*

This would be in contrast to another usage of 'Na' as a request, like in '*please*'.

They take on this status of someone that Lot should serve, because they passed by his house. Lot was merely expressing his politeness and hospitality toward the strangers, similar to Avraham.

'Lordship', like in Lords and Ladies of the Kings court, are people that a person of lower status serves. Lot learned this type of behavior (humility) from Avraham when they were together. It was part of providing hospitality. Avraham would use the hospitality to feed people and then get them to make blessings on the food.

Comment: +1 but i do not see how this answers my question

Comment: In other words please expound on " Lot was merely expressing his politeness and hospitality toward the strangers, similar to Avraham"

Comment: Does not the guest need to treat the host as a lord and not the other way?

Comment: No, @hazoriz, true hospitality is treating a guest, no matter how much of a rasha or how demanding, as a lord. Many of us fall short of this (I certainly do), but, nonetheless, most stories (whether in chumash or midrashim) about Abraham go out of their way to drive this point home

Comment: @hazoriz On what are you basing that idea? A polite host tries to see to every need of their guests. Anything they desire or request is provided freely. In a similar, but unrelated fashion, a Jewish King is a servant of his subjects. The King is in a state of absolute humility (Anavut). And yet, they are still the King.

Comment: @JoshK what is the reason(ing) of this behaviour

Comment: @YaacovDeane https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.5 i agree regarding humility of the king (halacha 6 here https://www.chabad.org/1188346/ ), buf still it is clear who is the lord

Comment: @hazoriz Your link to Shulchan Aruch isn't saying anything about treating the Host as a Lord. It's talking about having proper table manners and behaving well (Derech Eretz).

Comment: @YaacovDeane but it shows the atitude where do you see (in later sources) that the guesst is the lord?

Comment: @hazoriz The “attitude” is what ‘you’ are seeing. Traditional advice given to us all would be, ‘Remove the ‘you’, and the original (correct) intention will speak clearly to you.’

Comment: @YaacovDeane i am looking at it from the position of the guest if i whould be your guest i will see you as the lord, and if you treat me as the lord i would be very uncomfortable, (and would want to give you a big tip...)

Comment: https://learntorah.com/PeleYoetz/Pdf/English20.pdf or  https://learntorah.com/PeleYoetz/Pdf/Hebrew20.pdf

Comment: @hazoriz The Pela Yo’etz is great. And the essence of his comments in your link directed to the guest are to remember how great the mitzvah of Hachnasat Orchim is for the host in G-d’s eyes and to do what he can to help the host be successful in its fulfillment. He also emphasizes that one should avoid being a guest where possible because it is a burden on any potential host. But none of this suggests the guest should view the host as his Lord/superior.

Comment: @YaacovDeane ok but do you have proof of the opposite (guest is lord) from books after the tenach ?

Comment: @hazoriz In keeping with the spirit that “כל ישראל ערבים זה בזה”, I would point you to several of the links in the answer from JoshK. You could also reflect upon the long blessing from ברכות השחר which opens with ‘Baruch’ & closes with ‘Baruch’ and has the 2 Yehi Ratzon’s between. That enumerates how we are to interact with others and how we are to behave ourselves.

Comment: @YaacovDeane so they are masters but then they are always masters as we call people mr. - but what changes when they are guest they are the same masters

Comment: @hazoriz Rashi says they take on the status of ‘master’ when they pass by Lot’s house as potential guests. It isn’t a constant state of being.

Comment: @YaacovDeane this is my question this seems to contradict your sources,  please explain, what changes and source for that

Comment: @hazoriz For a more detailed explanation, not only of the 'clean' peshat used by Lot, but also the contrast to what Avraham meant when using similar language in Bereshit 18:3 and all the side implications which Rashi points to from Midrash Rabbah, see the Lubavitcher Rebbe's clarifications in Beurim l'Peirush Rashi, Bereshit, pp. 93-95.

Answer (score 2):

The Babylonian Talmud (Tractate Shabbat p.127a) argues, based on the incident just prior to this one in Parashat Vayera (the same three angels' encounter with Abraham Aveinu), that providing guests with proper hospitality is of greater merit even than receiving Hashem himself:

> Rav Yehuda said that Rav said on a related note: Hospitality toward
>   guests is greater than receiving the Divine Presence, as when Abraham
>   invited his guests it is written: “And he said: Lord, if now I have
>   found favor in Your sight, please pass not from Your servant” (Genesis
>   18:3). Abraham requested that God, the Divine Presence, wait for him
>   while he tended to his guests appropriately.
>
> ([Translation Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.127a?lang=bi))

I would also recommend reading [this excellent article](https://www.hidabroot.com/article/195984/Abraham-Chooses-KindnessWhat-it-Means-to-be-Spiritual) on Hidabroot.com posted on Vayera, stating:

> By writing the whole incident in full in the Torah, God wanted to
>   reveal to us a great principle: The importance of being hospitable to
>   a bunch of heathen idolaters is greater than receiving the presence of
>   God Himself!

We therefore see that one should treat even random passersby, regardless of their religion, as lords, i.e. offer them hospitality and act as their "servants" and that this is so important Hashem is happy if you take leave of Him to do so.

Comment: +1 but this does not answer my question

Comment: I've made the inference more explicit, @hazoriz, do you feel it answers your question now?

Comment: (The opinion that your bring from Shabbat holds that the "lords" was reffuring to G-d and not the guests https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.35b.10 but he does refure to himself as their slave) i do not see a logical inference maybe just providing them with hospitality  and not treating them as lords (by the way what does that mean?) is enough

Comment: @hazoriz I think you are getting hung up on the term "lord" which is being used as a figure of speech as it is throughout Tanakh. "I am your faithful servant" or "You are my lord" when used to refer to humans are just polite forms of address. The story of Channah randomly comes to mind- she was not, in fact, actually on Eli the Priest's payroll as a servant! https://www.sefaria.org/topics/Hannah?lang=bi

Comment: you are probobly right about me being "hung up" that is why i asked this question, but i guess all jews are servents to their king (no payroll nessesery) a heigh preist might be simular. (another place https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.4-13 but there it might be becouse he respected asovs strength...)

Comment: Excellent example from Bereshit, @hazoriz. It's just a figure of speech used to denote respect. To give you an analogy from our times, it would be like someone 3,000 years from now watching one of our cop shows, and a cop says "Sir, Please put the gun down" and the viewer thinks, "Wow, that guy in a trucker hat with no teeth holding up a gas station in Texas is a Knight of the British Empire? Weird!"

Comment: @JoshK The original source is from Bereshit Rabbah as Rashi points out to 18:3. It is necessary to contrast and compare what was said and intended by Avraham (which is these additional ideas enumerated in Midrash) with the simple usage from Lot. Please see the citation I mentioned from Beurim l’peirush Rashi al HaTorah in my comment to hazoriz.